# How to increase text size on graphs? [Using text(...) command]

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure

I have some texts on my graphs in MATLAB, and I want to increase size of the text. Do you know how to do that?

This is the line that I've used to add the text:

```
figure(1);
plot(x1, t, x2, t);
xlabel(Time);
ylabel(data); 
text(1, 1, ['Error:' (x2-x1)'m/s']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`FontSize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html#property_fontsize) property of the text object:

```
text(1, 1, ['Error:' num2str(x2-x1) 'm/s'], 'FontSize', 25);
```

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html#zmw57dd0e825589) for a list of all other font properties that you can set for a `text` object.

If you have an existing text object, you can store the handle to the text object and update the properties after creation:

```
htext = text(1, 1, 'mystring');

% And later....
set(htext, 'FontSize', 25)
```

Comment: You beat me by 4 seconds! :)

Comment: @matlabgui gotta keep you on your toes

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `get (text)` to see all the pproperties that you can modify when you create your text object.

The one your interested in is:

```
text ( 1, 1, 'str', 'FontSize', 20 );
```

for example.